# boolean array not replicating itself for other dimensions numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two arrays  `y` dims `(1x100)` and `X` dims `(3x100)`

I want to select all those values from `X` where `y` is 0 and all values where `y` is 1.

I have tried doing `X[y==0]` to get all those values where `y` is 0 but it doesn't work for dim 0 of `X` which is 3.

Any suggestions on how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to align dimensions correctly

```
X[:, y[0] == 0]
```

The first `:` specifies to grab everything in the first dimension.  Using the `y[0] == 0` in the second slot specifies that we are indexing the second dimension.

Comment: hey how did this align the dimensions correctly or how to do it if later I again get stuck in this problem, could you explain a bit, thanks